# Display user role name within WooCommerce API

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, post-meta

I am looking to display **user roles** when issuing a GET request e.g: https://yourdomain.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders.

The end goal is to use the **user roles** as a unique identifier in order to separate orders within an ERP based on the user role.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_prepare_shop_order_object', 'add_user_roles_field_to_order_object', 10, 3 );
function add_user_roles_field_to_order_object( $response, $order, $request ) {
    if ( empty( $response->data ) ) {
        return $response;
    }
    
    $user_id = $order->get_user_id();
    
    if ( is_int( $user_id ) && $user_id > 0 ) {
        $userdata = get_userdata( $user_id );
        $user_roles = $userdata->roles;
    } else {
        $user_roles = array();
    }
    
    $response->data['user_roles'] = $user_roles;

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Artemy that worked perfectly. Have a great day.